# tag merge or redirect

Tags: discussion, tags

I see an "ecological" tag has been added which is a poor choice as the proposed tag seems to point to "organic" in it's usage.

I suggest either deleting the "ecological" tag as most tags as nouns or verbs not adjectives.

If not this then a redirect to "organic".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that it's not a good tag, and given my druthers I'd just remove it altogether. Twenty-four hours after the last usage of a tag is removed from a questions, it will no longer be suggested when entering tags on new questions, so we could edit it out and it will disappear.

On the other hand, if we keep [ecological](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ecological) as a synonym of *something*, we already have the [sustainability](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sustainability) tag, which I think is a better match for the OP's intent in the [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24770/should-we-use-glyphosate-or-other-non-ecological-chemicals-in-our-gardens): the long-term effects of a pesticide on their garden.

Comment: Either works for me.  I do have a preference for tags being things/methods/actions as opposed to description.

Comment: Exactly! I'd even typed up a footnote about adjectives not making good tags because they're descriptive, as opposed to nouns or verbs which are tangible, but removed it before posting because I didn't think it added value.